# Convert Fragment Code to Activity Code

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am  trying to convert my Fragment Code to Activity code, but when I try to  run the Activity, the Activity opens but the data is null. Here my code

Fragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArmBicepFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ArmBicepFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http:.......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public ArmBicepFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("name").equals("bicep")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));

                                        // Genre is json array

                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());

        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog

        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbnail1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
        thumbnail1.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);


        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView nama = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        nama.setText("Nama = " + exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And here my convert result from Fragment (Nothing Error or warning)

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Felix on 5/15/2016.
 */
public class RekomendasiExercise extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http:............";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public RekomendasiExercise() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("nama").equals("abdominal")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));

                                        // Genre is json array
                                        // adding movie to movies array
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog

        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbnail1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
        thumbnail1.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);


        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView nama = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        nama.setText("Nama = " + exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: set your activity layout  in OnCreate method  like this @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onCreateView
```

is not a part of activity's lifecycle. You need to move stuff from this method to `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, exerciseList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        exerciseList.clear();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                if (obj.getString("nama").equals("abdominal")) {
                                    exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                    exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));

                                    // Genre is json array
                                    // adding movie to movies array
                                    exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
    }else{
        hidePDialog();
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put your codes in `onCreate` . Copy/paste the below codes.

```
public class RekomendasiExercise extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = AbdominalFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http:............";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public RekomendasiExercise() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("nama").equals("abdominal")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));

                                        // Genre is json array
                                        // adding movie to movies array
                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog

        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbnail1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
        thumbnail1.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);


        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView nama = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        nama.setText("Nama = " + exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.elite.youvaa.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArmBicepFragment extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ArmBicepFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http:.......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public ArmBicepFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), exerciseList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
            // Creating volley request obj
            JsonArrayRequest exerciseReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            hidePDialog();

                            exerciseList.clear();

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
                                    if (obj.getString("name").equals("bicep")) {
                                        exercise.setNama(obj.getString("nama"));
                                        exercise.setGambar1(obj.getString("gambar1"));

                                        // Genre is json array

                                        exerciseList.add(exercise);
                                    }
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(exerciseReq);
        }else{
            hidePDialog();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long id) {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());

        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); // layout of your dialog

        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbnail1 = (NetworkImageView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
        thumbnail1.setImageUrl(exerciseList.get(position).getGambar1(), imageLoader);


        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle("Detail");

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView nama = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        nama.setText("Nama = " + exerciseList.get(position).getNama());
        // similar add statements for other details

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```